# SP2-0552: Bind variable "VAR1" not declared

Tags: sql, oracle10g

```
set pagesize 0 echo off;
SET LINESIZE 30000 LONG 300000000 LONGCHUNKSIZE 30000 Trimspool on;

WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT SQL.SQLCODE

var1 timestamp
exec :var1 := select LOAD_TIME from xml_audit where subject_area=&2 and load_time=(select max(load_time) from xml_audit where status='PASSED');
```

I use the varibale in query down below but get error

```
SP2-0552: Bind variable "VAR1" not declared.
```

Please help me in this

Comment: What query down below?

Comment: If your intention is to define a `SQL*Plus` bind variable, the syntax is `var[iable] <<name of variable>> <<data type>>`.  I'm guessing that you want `var1` to be the name of the variable so you're missing the `var[iable]` declaration.  `timestamp` is also not a valid data type for a `SQL*Plus` bind variable.

Comment: Thanks i figured it out u r right :)

Answer (score 0):

In PL/SQL, you have to select into a variable.

> SELECT col INTO variable FROM table;

You also need to declare an anonymous block:

```
DECLARE
d_date DATE;
BEGIN
    SELECT sysdate INTO d_date FROM dual;
    SELECT col FROM table WHERE some_date = d_date
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow this syntax - this works in SQL PLus and should work in Toad, etc...:

```
VARIABLE x VARCHAR2(300);
EXEC :x:= 'MILLER';
SELECT ename FROM scott.emp WHERE ename = :x
/

SQL> VARIABLE x VARCHAR2(300);
SQL> EXEC :x:= 'MILLER';

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> SELECT ename FROM scott.emp WHERE ename = :x;

ENAME
----------
MILLER
```